# AngularJS testing with Jasmine: Check $window.off()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

How I can check $window.off() to have been called on $scope.$destroy(). $window is angular.element.

Example of code:

```
...
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    $window.off('event name');
});
...
```

Example of test:

```
it('should unbind all events from $window object', function () {
    spyOn($window, 'off').and.callThrough();

    $scope.$destroy();

    expect($window.off).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Result: Error: Expected spy off to have been called.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with this? We've been banging our heads against the keyboard for an hour trying to get the on/off spies to work in Jasmine :(

Comment: I literally just got it! See answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var rootScope ;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope))){
    rootScope = $rootScope;
}


it('should unbind all events from $window object', function () {
    spyOn($window, 'off').and.callThrough();

    $rootScope.$broadcast("$destroy", args);

    expect($window.off).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: The same result: Error: Expected spy off to have been called. Maybe I can find a way to check already assigned events on $window, but I don't know how to do it with angular.element ...

Comment: Please share the controller where you using the event

Comment: It is not a controller, it is directive link function.
'code' link: function(scope, element, attr) {

window = angular.element($window);
window.on('event');
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    window.off('event');
}); 
}

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a jQuery function, so you need to apply the spy onto however you initiate jQuery. The $window can stay as that is the element with the function attached, for example:

```
it('should unbind all events from $window object', function () {
    spyOn(angular.element.prototype, 'off').and.callThrough();

    $rootScope.$broadcast('$destroy', args);

    expect($window.off).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I should probably add that some jQuery libraries add a whole bunch of their own event listeners, in that case you want to make sure you get the most recent event after you initialise and add your own:

```
expect($el.off.calls.mostRecent().args).toContain('click', jasmine.any(Function));
```